# How to access indications with swift's core bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I've been attempting to integrate the Contour Next glucose meter using corebluetooth I've run into a limitation of core bluetooth that appears to prevent me from receiving blood glucose indications.

> If the specified characteristic’s configuration allows both
>   notifications and indications, calling this method enables
>   notifications only.

(source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue)

Unfortunately, the Contour Next does in fact allow both notifications and indications for the blood glucose measurements characteristic. So while I am able to successfully receive new measurements (via notifications) there doesn't appear to be any way to receive historical measurements (via indications).

You can see the an integration for android at https://github.com/jamorham/xDrip-plus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eveningoutpost/dexdrip/Services/BluetoothGlucoseMeter.java#L227 which enables both notifications and indications for that blood glucose measurements characteristic.

Is there some way to work around this limitation of core bluetooth or perhaps there's another way to integrate with bluetooth that doesn't use core bluetooth?

Comment: Not supporting indications shouldn't make any difference to the data you can access. The only difference between notifications and indications is whether the central acknowledges the receipt of the new data; this is handled by the Bluetooth stack and should be of no consequence to your app

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I'm missing something then. As I mentioned I am able to receive notifications for the characteristic but only for new measurements. When I ask for historic measurements I receive a confirmation that the request was handled but no measurements. What you say makes sense though so I think I'll have to hope that I've missed something and that some experimenting will yield some results. Thanks for the clarification at least.

Comment: So it turned out that the command I was sending to the Contour Next wasn't doing what I thought. According to the docs I was sending a "Request all" records command but as I mentioned, it wasn't returning anything. I swapped the command for one which instead requested "all records from the first to the last" and this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@paulw was correct, the issue was not in fact with the indications at all. It turned out that the command I was using wasn't working as expected ("Request all" command didn't work but "Request all records from first to last" did).